# How to make two div content vertical center?

Tags: html, css

I want to make two div content center "16) test". here please don't remove table. So. Please let me know. How i can do in my case using css ?

Result like [image]. No need line but content center

```html
<div style="width:946px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="float: left; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 30px; vertical-align: middle;text-align:center; " class="no">
            <strong>
                <span style="font-size:11.0pt">
                    16)
                </span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 765px; word-wrap: break-word;  vertical-align: middle;text-align:justify;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size:30.0pt">
                                <span style="line-height:115%">
                                    <span>Test</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size:15.0pt">
                                <span style="line-height:115%">
                                    <span>Test</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand quite what you want to do, maybe clarify by adding a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to add line-height property to 16

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div style="width:946px;">
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display:table-cell; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 30px; vertical-align: middle;text-align:center; " class="no">
            <strong>
                <span style="font-size:11.0pt">
                    16)
                </span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width: 765px; word-wrap: break-word;  vertical-align: middle;text-align:justify;position:relative;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size:30.0pt">
                                <span style="line-height:115%">
                                    <span>Test</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="position:absolute;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size:15.0pt">
                                <span style="line-height:115%">
                                    <span>Test</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment of text can be achieved easily by tables. Just make your floating divs displayed as table cell as in the code snippet below.

This code has a lot of inline styles and unused HTML. If needed you can use the code at the bottom to achieve the same result in very less code.

```html
<div style="width:946px;">
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display:table-cell; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 30px; vertical-align: middle;text-align:center; " class="no">
            <strong>
                <span style="font-size:11.0pt">
                    16)
                </span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width: 765px; word-wrap: break-word;  vertical-align: middle;text-align:justify;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size:30.0pt">
                                <span style="line-height:115%">
                                    <span>Test</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Simpler approach with inline styles-->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:11pt; padding: 0 15px 0 30px;"><b>16)</b></td>
    <td style="font-size:30.0pt; text-align: left; width: 765px;">Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```